# Install ubuntu 14.04 server on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi3

I'm new to raspberry pi and need to install ubuntu 14.04 server to it. I have raspberry pi 3.

When I tried installing noobs, downloaded from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/ But when I tried booting Rpi, it didn't show anything on the screen.

When I tried installing Raspbian Wheezy or Jessie, it was the same. Nothing showed up on the screen.

I was able to install ubuntu-mate-16.04 though but I need a CUI ubuntu. Also, the application I need on this Rpi isn't supported on Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there any way I can install an ubuntu server 14.04 or 15.04 or 15.10 on Raspberry Pi just the way I can install it as a Virtual Machine?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing raspbian jessie lite on your device. You can get it from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)

For windows, use win32 disk imager and write jessie-lite to your card.
Boot your device and it should work. You will have a CUI which is  debian.

Since you are keen on ubuntu, unfortunately there is nothing available at the moment similar to what you are looking for. But this should solve your purposes.

In my experience of raspberry pi, though it is limited, it works quite the same as ubuntu.

You might have to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once you start your device.